# How to use dbReadTable with PostgreSQL db with enormous size

Tags: r, postgresql, large-data, database

Is there a way to use the dbReadTable to read in only several thousand rows at a time?
For example, I am trying to read in (out of necessity) a d.table from a Postgres data base that is 6 million rows long. When I try to read in the d.table as a whole, RStudio freezes up eventually or just never completes.
Can I specify to read in say rows 1-100,000, then rows 100,001-200,000, then rows 200,001-300,000, for example?
I am familiar with specifying which columns to read in to expedite the process so that is not something I am concerned with.

Comment: You need to do this in SQL with [`LIMIT` and `OFFSET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-limit.html).

Answer (score 0):

As @r2evans suggests, consider running SQL with iterative [`dbGetQuery()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/RPostgreSQL.pdf) calls to read in queries that slice table per 100,000 rows:

```
# VECTOR OF 60 SQL STATEMENTS TO QUERY 100,000 ROWS SKIPPING 100000 EACH TIME
sqls <-  paste0("SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM mytable LIMIT 100000 OFFSET ", 
                seq(0, 5900000, by=100000))

# ROW BIND 60 DATASETS OF 100,000 ROWS
finaldf <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sqls, function(s) dbGetQuery(conn, s))
```

---

However, I assume this `do.call` may be very slow and extensive to run. Consider third-party packages (`plyr`, `dplyr`, `data.table`) to row bind the list of retrieved dataframes from PostGres:

```
postgresdfs <- lapply(sqls, function(s) dbGetQuery(conn, s))

plyr::rbind.fill(postgresdfs)       

plyr::ldply(postgresdfs, data.frame)

dplyr::bind_rows(postgresdfs)

data.table::rbindlist(postgresdfs)
```